# Cannot cast from String to float in java

Tags: java, android, types

```
long l = ((File)localObject).length();
  if (l >= 1024L)
  {
    if (l >= 1048576L)
    {
      if (l >= 1073741824L)
        str = Float.toString(Math.round(100.0F * ((float)l / 1.073742E+09F)) / 100.0F) + " GB";
      else
        str = Float.toString(Math.round(100.0F * ((float)str / 1048576.0F)) / 100.0F) + " MB";
    }
    else
      str = Float.toString(Math.round(100.0F * ((float)str / 1024.0F)) / 100.0F) + " KB";
  }
  else
    str = Long.toString(str) + " B";
```

else
        str = Long.toOctalString(str) + " B";
    }
    return (String)str;
}

Another error in 16 th
Here i got the error in 9 th line and 12 th line  Cannot cast from String to float in java

Comment: What causes you to think a float cast of a string should work?   What if the string has an illegal format (`"ABCNOTA NUMBER"`)?  How can a cast work with bad data?  Have you seen documentation or a tutorial that makes it look like this should work?

Comment: There's an error on the last line: maybe you should write `str = Long.toString(l) + " B"`

Comment: Also, please read the book "Clean code" by R.C. Martin. Your code is horrible to read with nested if-else-statements, magic numbers, nested arguments. What if a team member is to understand this code? That is impossible. I even think that in a week or two you won't be able to understand it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to cast the String `str` to a float. Probably you have a mistake and you are supposed to use the `l` variable instead.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose `str` is a String, in which case you need to use `Float.valueOf(str)` instead of `(float)str`.

Or more likely you meant `(float)l` instead of `(float)str`.

And as mentioned by enzom83, your last line should probably be:

```
str = Long.toString(l) + " B";
```

Comment: here i got the error in line str = Long.toString(str) + " B"; The method toString(long) in the type Long is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 3):

use `parseFloat` method `Float.parseFloat(str)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `(float)str` when `str` is a `String`.

Replace it with this (and catch possible exceptions!): `Float.valueOf(str)`

Answer (score 1):

Hm, sorry for my English

If `str` is a `String` that you can't convert into a float like this `(float)str`, you must use a `Float method` called `parseFloat(String s)`, which returns a new float initialized to the value represented by the specified String